# Jquery - Sending post form, get value and show div?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Greetins,

Dears, i'm trying to do something with jQuery but still not work. I've a form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" >

    Cliente: {HTML::select('cliente', $clientes, $cliente,"check(this);")}
   <div id="oculto" visible="false" style="visibility:hidden;padding:30px 0px 20px 0px">
    Rut: <input type = "text" name="rut" id="rut"/>
    <input type = "text" name="digitov" id ="digitov" style="width:20px"/>
</div>
       <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name= "buscar_registros" id="buscar_registros"/>
   </form>
```

And if this form is submited, I need get the value from "cliente" and after that, display a hidden div what i've.

```
        <div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {HTML::select('nombre', $nombre , $nombre)}
    </br></br></br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$cliente}" />
        <table>
            <td width="10%">Desde: {HTML::calendario( 'desde', $hoy )}</td>
            <td width="10%">Hasta: {HTML::calendario( 'hasta', $hoy )}</td>
            <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="factura" id="factura" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de factura"/></td>
            <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="estado_pago" id="estado_pago" placeholder="N&uacute;mero estado pago"/></td>
            <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="sifacturada" id="sifacturada" value="facturada"/>Facturadas</td>
            <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="nofacturada" id="nofacturada" value="no_facturada"/>No Facturadas</td>
        </table>
         <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; margin-top: -0.8em;">  
        <input type="submit"  value="Filtrar" name= "filtros" /> 
        </div>             
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I do that with jQuery?? D:

I'm triyng to do something using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#form1').submit(function(){
             jQuery('#hidden').show();   
    });
 });
</script>
```

But doesn't work

Comment: Not understand, you tried post form and after display the result value in div element hidden? Why not use ajax for this? After post form the page html is not accessible. For your necessity the correct is use ajax, then without refresh the page insert de return value in hidde div.

Comment: You should disable the default action of submit of form as well.